# How can I display swedish characters in Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, character, mojibake

I have a database that I extract data from to my Android project. There are some strings of text there with the swedish letters å, ä, ö written as : √•=å, √§=ä, √δ=ö. What would be the best way of converting these symbols to the actual letters before I print them on the textview in the app? Is a substitution, like replace √• with å, the way to go? How would that be entered in the query that is now fetching the data:

```
public Cursor getAlternative1(long categoryid, int questionid) {
                final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT question, image, alternative, questionid, correct FROM tbl_question a INNER JOIN tbl_alternative b ON a._id=b.questionid AND b.categoryid=a.categoryid WHERE a.categoryid=? AND a._id=?";

                Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(categoryid), String.valueOf(questionid)});
                if (cursor != null) {
                      cursor.moveToFirst();
                 }
                return cursor;
            }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you inserting the data into your database? When I insert Swedish letters into mine, it all comes out into my `ListView` as expected.

Comment: They are inserted as √•=å, √§=ä, √δ=ö, these symbols representing the letters. It is the translation i am after, if the format above is a known format like utf-8, or if I should do a replace this for that etc.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like when inserting, where you would like to have `å`, you actually insert `√•=å` - correct? Do you do this as a string literal (say, `String text = "√•=å";`) or do you let Android handle the UTF-16 encoding (say, `String text = "å";`)? Since `String`s are already UTF-16 encoded, you shouldn't need to handle the translation yourself - it's already capable of handling accented characters without any extra work on your part.

Comment: I am sorry that I was unclear, in my database (which I import as it is, I don't enter any data myself) the letters are represented by √•, etc. For HTML there is an easy way of writing å for example as &auml, and the browser "understands" it. Am I missing a similar conversion? How do I handle such accented characters that you speak of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your string data was originally encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but are getting misinterpreted as [MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman).

The first thing to do is make sure your data is being stored in the database correctly.  You can use `SELECT HEX(SomeColumn)` to see the raw bytes that are being stored for the string.  The default encoding in SQLite is UTF-8, so a correctly-encoded string will have `C3A5` for `å`, `C3A4` for `ä`, and `C3B6` for `ö`.  If you see `E2889AE280A2`, `E2889AC2A7`, `E2889AE28882`, then the misinterpretation of the characters (å→√•, ä→√§, ö→√δ) is happening before the data gets into the DB.  If you just see `8C`, `8A`, and `9A`, then the reverse misinterpretation is being made.

If your database is correct, then it's probably an I/O routine that thinks the system encoding is UTF-8 when it's really MacRoman.  Try something like `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "macintosh");`.

Comment: Hi! I did as you said and in my database E2889AE280A2, E2889AC2A7, E2889AE28882 are used for å,ä,ö. So if the misinterpretation as you say happens before the data gets into the DB, I should try to interpret it back from MacRoman? I cannot change the db, it is imported from another project and reused. Thanks for clearing the fog and introducing me to different formats!

Comment: `str = new String(str.getBytes("macintosh"), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old post, but if you are importing the data into sqlite using windows cmd shell, try doing this in the shell:

c:> chcp 65001

This will change the code page of cmd shell to utf 8

c:> sqlite3 database.db < inserts.sql

where inserts.sql is a UTF-8 (WITHOUT BOM CHARACTER!!) sequence of inserts. You can create that kind of file using Notepad++

Hope it helps